# Application of Borel Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve the question below and after an hour no success yet! Here is the question:

$X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent poisson random variables with $EX_j = \lambda_j$. Assume that $ 0 < \lambda_j < 1$. Define $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$. We need to show that:

$$ \text{if } \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_j = \infty \text{ then} \frac{S_n}{ES_n} \rightarrow 1 \text{ almost surely}$$.

I appreciate if you could give me some hints on how I should approach this question.

There is a hint on this question that Borel-Cantelli lemma should be used. As you know Borel-Cantelli (lemma 2) says:

Let $A_1, A_2, ...$ be events in the probability space. Then:

if $A_1, A_2, ...$ are independent and $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} p(A_k) = \infty$ then $\rightarrow p(A_k, \text{ infinitely often}) = 1$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are $j$ and $k$ related?

Comment: Why does the title say "Application of Borel Cantelli"? The body doesn't mention the Borel–Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Hi @joriki, I edited the question...The hint on this question is to use Borel-Cantelli and that's why I use the title.

Comment: That missing information should be added to the question itself; people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question. It's currently not clear from the title whether *you* would like to apply the Borel–Cantelli lemma or whether this is a hint that's part of the question.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Lemme add that too...

Comment: I hadn't come accross the abbreviation "i.o." for "infinitely often" before. You might want to explain it, or at least punctuate it correctly to make clear that it's an abbreviation :-)

Comment: The result is true. At the moment, I fail to see how a proof may be based on either one of Borel-Cantelli lemmas (the proof I know is not).

Comment: My (remaining) problem is to show that $\sum_n \mathbb{P}[|S_n-\mu_n|>\varepsilon \cdot \mu_n]<\infty$ where $\mu_n := \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j$. Tschebyscheff-inequality doesn't work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First we remark that $S_n \sim \text{Poi} \left(\mu_n \right)$ where $\mu_n := \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j$. Moreover, $\mathbb{E}S_n = var S_n=\mu_n$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By applying Tschebyscheff-inequality

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ \left| \frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}S_n} -1 \right|>\varepsilon \right] \leq \frac{1}{(\varepsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}S_n)^2} \cdot \text{var} S_n = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu_n} \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty)$$

since $\mu_n= \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \to \infty$. Hence $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}S_n} \to 1$ in probability. Now let $n_k := \inf\{n; \mathbb{E}S_n \geq k^2\}$. Then the same calculation shows

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ \left| \frac{S_{n_k}}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_k}} -1 \right|>\varepsilon \right] \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \cdot \frac{1}{k^2} \\
\Rightarrow \sum_k \mathbb{P}\left[ \left| \frac{S_{n_k}}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_k}} -1 \right|>\varepsilon \right] \leq \sum_k \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \cdot \frac{1}{k^2}  < \infty$$

By applying the Lemma of Borel-Cantelli we obtain $\frac{S_{n_k}}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_k}} \to 1$  almost surely as $k \to \infty$. Since

$$\frac{S_{n_k}(w)}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_{k+1}}} \leq \frac{S_n(w)}{\mathbb{E}S_n} \leq \frac{S_{n_{k+1}}(w)}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_k}}$$

for all $n_k<n \leq n_{k+1}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{E}S_{n_{k+1}}}{\mathbb{E}S_{n_k}} \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$ we conclude $\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}S_n} \to 1$ almost surely.

Comment: What a nice answer...I've read it several times and I enjoy the way you use different tools to solve this question...thank a lot.